# Why does `IPython.display.Javascript(...)` work to run a Javascript command in a Jupyter cell but not in an IPython magic?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython, ipython-magic, jupyter-extensions

I'm trying to write a [Jupyter nbextension](https://github.com/bskinn/jupyter-tempvars) where the user can configure the notebook-wide extension behavior using IPython magics. I'm planning on siting the configuration data on the JS side, under an application-specific key in `Jupyter.notebook.metadata`, `"tempvars"`. In order to do this, I need the magics to be able to change the appropriate values within that `....metadata["tempvars"]`.

***If I load a Jupyter notebook*** and make metadata changes using `IPython.display.Javascript` directly from a notebook cell, they apply successfully.

JS console:

```js
>> Jupyter.notebook.metadata["tempvars"]["universal"] = false
<- false
```

Jupyter cell:

```py
[ ]: from IPython.display import Javascript
[ ]: Javascript("Jupyter.notebook.metadata['tempvars']['universal'] = true")
```

JS console:

```js
>> Jupyter.notebook.metadata["tempvars"]["universal"]
<- true  // CHANGED AS EXPECTED
```

***However***, if I try to do the same thing from inside a magic, it does *not* work:

From my magics definition module, within the broader `jupyter_tempvars` package (please don't mind the very WIP implementation):

```py
from IPython.core.magic import register_line_magic

def load_ipython_extension(ipython):
    @register_line_magic
    def tempvars(line):
        subcommand, arg = line.strip().split(" ")
        if subcommand == "universal":
            Javascript(f"Jupyter.notebook.metadata['tempvars']['universal'] = {arg.lower()};")
```

From a freshly loaded notebook, starting in the JS console:

```js
>> Jupyter.notebook.metadata["tempvars"]["universal"] = false
<- false
```

Jupyter cells:

```py
[ ]: %load_ext jupyter_tempvars
```

```py
[ ]: %tempvars universal true
```

JS console:

```
>> Jupyter.notebook.metadata["tempvars"]["universal"]
<- false  // DID NOT CHANGE
```

**What is different about the IPython magic context that is making this `Javascript` call fail?**

Answer (score 0):

According to the IPython docs for the [`Javascript` object](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.display.html#IPython.display.Javascript):

> Create a Javascript display object given raw data.
>
> When this object is returned by an expression or passed to the display function, it will result in the data being displayed in the frontend.

As it turns out, the rendering of the JS code upon simply being returned by an expression is ***not*** a universal behavior. In particular, inside an IPython magic, you *must* pass the `Javascript` instance to `IPython.display.display()` in order for it to be rendered.

This is what IPython does in its own built-in (and deprecation-pending) [`%javascript` magic](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/96f8b20fb716570b869d05740e249b4fabef8e00/IPython/core/magics/display.py#L47-L56).